# Materialize.css autocomplete not working with Polymer

Tags: javascript, jquery, polymer, polymer-1.0, materialize

I am trying to use [Materialize.css autocomplete](http://materializecss.com/forms.html#autocomplete) with my Polymer project.

Console Log:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).autocomplete is not a function
```

My Code:

```
<div class="input-field">
    <input type="text" id="assemp" class="autocomplete" value="{{emps::input}}">
    <label for="assemp">Assigned Employee(s)</label>
</div>
```

Script:

```
attached : function() {
            $('input.autocomplete').autocomplete({
                data: {
                    "Apple": null,
                    "Microsoft": null,
                    "Google": 'http://placehold.it/250x250'
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: Are you loading the materialize JavaScript script in your HTML? See http://materializecss.com/getting-started.html

Comment: I'm running into the same issue

Comment: You should read [TypeError: "x" is not a function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Not_a_function)

Comment: You can find an answer for autocomplete using stackoverflow.com/a/43133503/3295819

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 $(document).ready(function () {$('input.autocomplete').autocomplete({
            data: {
                "Apple": null,
                "Microsoft": null,
                "Google": null
            }});});
```

Comment: Please explain your answer

Comment: put autocomplete in jquery function

Comment: @Liam I had the same issue, this is the correct answer for me. The reason is because the materialize.js file loads the autocomplete plugin inside a $(document).ready block, so if you try to use autocomplete before the document is loaded it will not be defined. I had the same problem for chips (material_chip plugin) which in turn will use autocomplete if specified.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are loading the most recent materialize.js file. I had an older version where the autocomplete plugin was not in the JS and it was throwing that same error. Went away after I updated. However i still can't get the autocomplete to work. :(

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar issue with react.  If I execute the code within jquery it seems to work.

```
$(() => {
  $(...).autocomplete();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

my workaround:

copy function:

```
/**************************
* Auto complete plugin  *
*************************/

$.fn.autocomplete = function (options) {
// Defaults
var defaults = {
    data: {}
};

options = $.extend(default

(...)

}); // End of $(document).ready (1)

/*******************
 *  Select Plugin  *
 ******************/
```

from materialize.js (line number ~3000) 
or 
from source file /js/forms.js (line number ~281)

remove last line:

```
}); // End of $(document).ready (1)
```

it closing function started more more before...

and put it manualy into your javascript function body

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
//paste it here
})
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem was solved by downgrading my jQuery version to V2.1.4 as Materialize CSS uses.

Comment: Mind you, this isn't explicitly stated in the documentation. Another reason to stop library dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as [Wesley Williams`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6727226/wesley-williams) mentioned before, the version of Materialize JS file does matter! I has this js file of version *0.97.3* and I could never get a simple standard example to work.

In the end it turned out that this version does not support the function *autocomplete*, so I had to upgrade to the newest version and it worked fine.